# How to detect iCloud user when phone is in airplane mode?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, userid

Firstly I am aware of this post: [How to identify iCloud logged in user in airplane mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884575/how-to-identify-icloud-logged-in-user-in-airplane-mode/25885641#25885641)

It doesn't seem to have an answer though. One answer talks about detecting Internet connectivity and the other talks about wether or not the user has changed.

Here is my code:

```
container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            var title: String!
            var message: String!

            if error != nil{
                title = "Error"
                message = "An error occurred = \(error)"
            } else {
                //title = "No errors occurred getting info"
                switch status{
                case .Available:
                    message = "The user is logged in to iCloud"
                    title = "GOOD"
                    print("determined status was available")
                    self.shouldPullFromICloud()
                    //self.displayAlertWithTitle(title, message: message)
                case .CouldNotDetermine:
                    message = "Could not determine if the user is logged" +
                    " into iCloud or not"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .NoAccount:
                    message = "User is not logged into iCloud"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .Restricted:
                    message = "Could not access user's iCloud account information"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                }
                print(title, message)
            }
        })
    }
```

Seems pretty stupid that you need an internet connection to see if a user is signed into iCloud. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

P.S.
If that other post does contain the answer to my question can you please highlight it for me? I couldn't find it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Airplane mode simply turns off cellular and wifi data capabilities. In this case, checking reachability should serve the same purposes as detecting Airplane mode. Here is a standard lib snippet that will check for reachability:

```
func connectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        return false
    }
    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []

    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: I am using this for other reasons but I still need a way of getting a user's ID no matter if they are on airplane mode or not ya know?